# SAS right most characters

Tags: function, character, sas

Let's say I have a list of 10000 records with random patterns except for the last 8 digits which are dates created. How do I pick up the most recent unique record?

For example, below is a list 6 records. I want to manipulate data only on the two most recent unique tables such as abc789 and xyz789. I imagine this would involved using the max function and a right function. I am also having a hard time trying to find the function needed for the right most 3 characters, as in right(abc123,3) should equal 123, but this is not the case in SAS.

Record Name: 
abc123
abc456
abc789
xyz123
xyz456
xyz789

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to create a pair of new variables with the `abc` and `123` separately, then sort as needed.

```
pattern_id = substr(pattern,1,length(pattern)-8);
patern_date= substr(pattern,length(pattern)-7,8);
```

The `length` function returns number of characters used.  Test to make sure the `pattern` variable has enough characters that this is possible.